# XMLPad temp files

Tags: configuration

I am using XMLPad 3.0 to edit my app.config files in a .NET application. For some reason, XMLPad is leaving the ~filename.xml files around in the folder where the XML file I just edited are.

Is there a setting to turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off "create backup files" in global settings | files